# How to get next date from given array of days after 9 days in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Can anyone help me with to get next date (x in mm/dd/yyyy format)after 9 days of period from a given banchmark date(y in mm/dd/yyyy format) ? x should only be from a given array of days.

Example-
Given array of days

```
SSA = [1,3,6,9,10,15,18,23,27,28,31]
```

1. If `y = 06/26/2018`
   Then after 9 days `26 + 9 = 07/05/2018`
   Desired answer = `07/06/2018`.
2. If `y = 06/03/2018`
   Then after 9 days `03+ 9 = 06/12/2018`
   Desired answer = `06/15/2018`

Comment: First add 9 days to `y`. Get the day of month from that, then loop through `SSA` and return the first number greater than that.

Comment: What happens if 9 days is `7/31/2018`? There's no number after that. Or if 9 days is `6/30/2018`, since `6/31/2018` isn't a valid date? Should these both return day 1 in the next month?

Comment: Yes , if 9th day is 7/31/2019 then answer is 8/01/2018.

Comment: OK, so if the loop doesn't found anything, you use `SSA[0]`. Every step is simple, just put them all together.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use getTime to add your days in miliseconds, so to add 9 days at 06/26/2018 you add 9*24*60*60*1000 to the gettime and you go in 7/5/2018 :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript new Date()</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var SSA = [1,3,6,9,10,15,18,23,27,28,31];
var y = "06/26/2018";
var d = new Date(y);
d = new Date( d.getTime() + 9*24*60*60*1000 );
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (d.getMonth()+1)+'/'+(d.getDay()+1 +SSA[0])+ '/'+ d.getFullYear()+' --- '+d;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```